# IE11 audio tag not working

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, html5-audio

I have an intranet site running on a Linux server with Apache that plays court recordings for our judges. I use the `<audio>` tag to play the MP3 file, which is located on a NAS shared via an entry in FSTAB.

This works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox; and by everything I've read *should* work in IE11; however, I keep getting the fallback error message saying that the HTML5 audio tag is not supported.

I've seen various posts on this, but none of them helped. I do have the

```
<meta http-equiv-“X-UA-Compatible” content=”IE=edge”/>
```

line in my `<head>`, my page does have a `<title>`, and my audio is only available in MP3 format.

The code for my audio tag:

```
<audio src="/jaudio/<?php echo $file;?>" type="audio/mp3" controls>
```

HTML5 audio not supported

Comment: Do you have a doctype? Also the meta tag you have here is incorrect. Should be `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` (`=` not `-` and `"` not `“`/`”`).

Comment: This is my doctype:
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Let me try those changes and let you know...

Comment: The changes to meta didn't fix it, unfortunately...

Comment: That's an HTML4 doctype. Maybe try the HTML5 one: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Nope, still no luck.

Comment: Probably going to need an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then.

Comment: I found it...I started going letter by letter on everything, and found a typo in my meta tag -- when I fixed it based on your first suggestion, I had two "="...Thanks for the help!